Solving quadratic modular equations
I am interested in how to solve equations of the form
$x^2 \equiv d \mod p$.
I did try to read into the topic.
In the book I am reading one is introduced to the Legendre-Symbol, then to the Jacobi-Symbol. Using those one can prove the following Lemma:
Let p be prime such that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and let $d$ be a quadratic residue mod $p$. Then $d^{\frac{p+1}{4}}$ is a solution of $x^2 \equiv d \mod p$.
After this Lemma the Tonelli-Shanks algorithm is introduced to be able to solve $x^2 \equiv d \mod p$ for arbitrary $p$ prime.
My Question is the following:
How does one "normally" approach equations like $x^2 \equiv d \mod p$?
Does one first see if $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, and if so then uses the lemma. And if no then uses Tonelli-Shanks. Or is there some other approach that gives a solution without needing a lot of calculations?

I just use the algo from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm without concern of whether its $3 \bmod 4$ or legendre symbol or all that

Comment: I try to show you a simply way for small p. Let $p=7$, we have:
$x^2\equiv d \bmod 7\Rightarrow x^2=7k+d$
$d=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$
Then we filter d due to the Euler's criterion; d has quadric residue if:
$d^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv 1 \bmod p$
$\frac{7-1}2=3$
We check the remainders and find:
$6^3\equiv -1 \bmod 7$
$5^3\equiv -1\bmod 7$
$3^3\equiv -1 \bmod 7$
So only remainders $d= 1, 2$ and $4$ have quadric residue.We may write:
$k= \space\space   2, \space\space 3, \space\space 5,\space\space  9,\space\space 11,\space\space 14,\space\space  17,\space\space  20,\space\space   24, \cdot\cdot\cdot$
$d=   \space\space 2,\space\space  4,\space\space  1,\space\space  1,\space\space  4,\space\space\space\space  2,\space\space \space\space  2,\space\space\space\space   4,\space\space\space  \space\space  1, \cdot\cdot\cdot$
$x^2= 16, 25, 36, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, \cdot\cdot\cdot$
So for a computer program for brute force we better first filter the residues for a given prime.
